# SlimDX for c# XAudio2 Effects (Reverb)

Tags: c#, effects, slimdx, xaudio2

How can I add a reverb effect to a voice? I can't find any XAudio2Reverb class or anything. 
I did, however, come across [this page](http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/source/browse/branches/v2/Source/SlimDX.XAudio2/Fx/Reverb.cs?r=1779).

It looks like the code for the reverb effects was written but on the downloaded SDK and redistributable this class (not even the XAudio2.FX namespace) doesn't exist, so there is a link or something where I can this version of SlimDX2 or do I have to download the source and compile it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using SharpDX. It's far more complete and well documented.